# Get the /dev/tty??? for Raspberry Pi

Tags: usb

I'm connecting a USB-to-RS-485 adapter to my Raspberry Pi.

[image]

[image]

How do I know which */dev/ttyXXX* it corresponds to? I'm using Raspberry Pi model B+

[image]

**Update with goldilock's answer:**

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A refinement to oh.dae.su's method:

```
dmesg | grep "tty"
```

Another trick would be to save the state of `/dev` before plugging it in:

```
ls -1 /dev > dev.txt
```

Plug it in, do it again, check what's changed:

```
ls -1 /dev > dev2.txt
diff dev.txt dev2.txt
```

When you're done, `rm dev*.txt` to delete the two files.

Serial device attached to USB ports will generally end up with that in their name.  In this case it looks to be `ttyUSB0`.

> By the way, how do I know which port (out of the 4) has a serial port? by trial and error?

All the physical USB ports on the pi are equivalent; none of them has any special properties relative to another.

The device node name is not based on a static numbering of the USB ports, such that if you plugged it into the port next over you would get `ttyUSB2` instead.  It's based on the order in which the interface is created by the kernel (notice, no serial devices plugged in, no `ttyUSB` entries in `/dev`).

So, if you plugged another serial device into another USB port with the first one still plugged in, that would be `ttyUSB1`.  However, if you unplugged the original one first, that dev node interface would be removed, and the new one would probably end up as `ttyUSB0`.  But if you removed the original one *after* plugging the second one in, `ttyUSB0` would disappear, but `ttyUSB1` would still exist (i.e., they don't get re-assigned as long as they remain plugged in).

Sometimes a USB interface dev node may end up remaining in existence for a bit after you remove the device, so, e.g, if you unplug the device and then plug it in right away again, it *may* end up as `ttyUSB1` even though you never had two devices plugged in at the same time.

There are ways to make sure a device always has the same dev node name when you plug it in, a name you assign to it.  However, this is a bit tricky (and the subject of a different question), so unless this really becomes a problem for you, don't worry about it.  As long as you are only using one serial device at a time and aren't plugging it in and out quickly it will always be `ttyUSB0`.

Comment: Your second solution is also nice! For the `dmesg | grep "dev/tty"` you have to be careful. In my experience the `dmesg` output is typically without the `dev`.

Comment: Thanks @goldilocks, it's indeed ttyUSB0 thanks. Just wondering, I've 4 USB ports on raspberry pi model b+ , however there's only ttyUSB0. Why there're no ttyUSB1, ttyUSB2, ttyUSB3?

Comment: @user1872384 you've got 4 physical USB ports, but only one has a serial port (or tty) attached, so you only see `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

Comment: I see. By the way, how do I know which port (out of the 4) has a serial port? by trial and error?

Comment: I've added some stuff at the bottom about this.

Answer (score 5):

If you've only got one device attached, it'll most likely always get `/dev/ttyUSB0`. Things get more complex when you have multiple adapters, and then the `/dev/serial/by-id/*` aliases become more useful. On my machine, they look like:

- `/dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_A10175UI-if00-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB0`
- `/dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_USB__-__Serial-if00-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB1`

The first one is a real FTDI adapter (it has a serial number, A10175UI), the second a cheap clone of an FTDI (no serial number). If you access the port by its `by-id` location, it'll pick up the same physical adapter every time.

Answer (score 4):

After you have plugged in the device to the USB port call

```
dmesg
```

In one of the last lines of output normally you will see the `dev/ttyxxx` to which it is attached.

Comment: Thanks @oh.dae.su. However, I couldn't comprehend the output of dmesg.

Answer (score 4):

I have the following script (found somewhere on the Internet) which lists USB devices together with human-readable names:

```
#!/bin/bash

for sysdevpath in $(find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev); do
    (
        syspath="${sysdevpath%/dev}"
        devname="$(udevadm info -q name -p $syspath)"
        [[ "$devname" == "bus/"* ]] && exit
        eval "$(udevadm info -q property --export -p $syspath)"
        [[ -z "$ID_SERIAL" ]] && exit
        echo "/dev/$devname - $ID_SERIAL"
    )
done
```

The output looks like this:

```
/dev/input/mouse0 - 0000_USB_OPTICAL_MOUSE
/dev/input/event0 - 0000_USB_OPTICAL_MOUSE
/dev/ttyUSB0 - 1a86_USB2.0-Serial
/dev/ttyACM0 - Arduino__www.arduino.cc__0042_55936343933351B030F0
/dev/input/event1 - Logitech_USB_Receiver
/dev/input/event2 - Logitech_USB_Receiver
/dev/input/mouse1 - Logitech_USB_Receiver
/dev/sda2 - WD_Elements_2620_-0:0
/dev/sda - WD_Elements_2620_-0:0
/dev/sda1 - WD_Elements_2620_-0:0
```

Comment: This script does not work for me. With my Raspberry Pi 4, with nothing connected to any of the serial ports (accessing pi by ssh) I run the script and get the following output: /dev/ttyUSB0 - Silicon_Labs_CP2102_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller_0001
.