# RPi 4B Debian Bullseye ttyUSB0 is missing

Tags: pi-4, usb

**Situation**: RPi 4B Debian Bullseye using raspberry imager e.g. 64bit lite

**Problem**: After logging in 'ls /dev' does not show ttyUSB0. It has been visible 2 days ago. I guess running bookworm.

Hints: I tested already...

1. installing ALL available images for RPi4B => no solution!
2. research in WWW => no solution!
3. I tested different harware like RPi3B and another RPi4B

Comment: What have you plugged in that should show up as ttyUSB0?

Comment: why would you change from bookworm to bullseye? Perhaps whatever device showed up as ttyUSB0 is supported in bookworm, but not supported in the earlier bullseye

Comment: You might [start by reading this Q&A.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88079/get-the-dev-tty-for-raspberry-pi)

Comment: It may be changed to /dev/ttyAMA1, ttyAMA0 is the console.